# Django-allauth Password Reset Email not sending

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a weird problem where my allauth email will send to verify new user email address but no email will send for resetting the password. I have checked the gmail account from which the email should be sent but it only shows the verification emails as sent, its as though nothing is being done when the user clicks the reset password button on the template side. I'm not sure what I am missing..

My template

```
  <body class="login-page container-fluid">
    <div class="row vygr-login">
      <div class="user_card">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="form_container col vygr-signup-container">
              {% load i18n %}
              <form class="signup" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">

                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                {% include "account/snippets/already_logged_in.html" %}
                {% endif %}

                <p class="registration-element" style="font-size: 2rem;">{% trans "Trouble Logging In?" %}</p>
                <p class=" registration-element">{% trans "Enter your email and we'll send you a link to get back into your account." %}</p>
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" class="password_reset">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {% for field in form %}
                  {{ field }}
                  {% endfor %}

                  <input class="signup-button" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Reset My Password' %}">
                  <p class="" style="text-align: center;">{% blocktrans %}Please contact us if you have any trouble resetting your password.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
                </form>
            </div>
      
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```